# Why does typedoc ignore my interface declaration?

Tags: typescript, typedoc

```
type S=string|undefined;
declare global {
    export interface String {
        /**
         * returns string between borders
         * @param   borderA - left border
         * @param   borderB - right border
         * @param aIsFirst - true if borderA is first, false if is last
         * @param bIsFirst - true if borderB is first, false if is last
         */
        between(borderA:S, borderB:S, aIsFirst:boolean, bIsFirst:boolean):S;
    }
}
```

typedoc command: `typedoc --out ./documentation/ src/`

It generates the folder with HTML, taken from README.md, but no traces of my interface is ever found there...

Comment: Very curious about the same thing. My error is `Block, defined at src/types/block.types.ts:2, is referenced by EssentialEth.getBlock.getBlock but not included in the documentation.`

Answer (score 1):

TypeDoc will only document things that are exported by one of your entry points.  If your exporting Foo but not IFoo, you will receive an error that it's used "but not included in the documentation"...

See https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/1739